# Problem with AOT (ahead of time) in a generic method after built to UWP and Il2CPP

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, il2cpp

I have a generic method for trying to get a generic value from a dictionary via key using my own `TryGetValue` like (of course cropped a lot to the essential)

```
public class BaseExample
{
    public virtual bool TryGetValue<T>(string key, out T value)
    {
        value = default;
        return false;
    }
}

public class Example : BaseExample
{
    private Dictionary<string, Item> _items = new Dictionary<string, Item>();

    public override bool TryGetValue<T>(string key, out T value)
    {
        value = default;
        if (!GetItem(key, value, out var setting)) { return false; }

        value = (T)setting.Value;
        return true;
    } 

    private bool GetItem<T>(string key, T value, out Item item)
    {
        item = null;

        if (!_items.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            item = null;
            return false;
        }

        item = _items[key];

        return true;
    }
}
```

This works in the Unity Editor but as soon as this is built to UWP and IL2CPP as soon as I try to run the method with e.g.

```
var value = example.TryGetValue<int>("SomeKey");
```

It throws a

```
 System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to call method 'Example::TryGetValue<System.Int32>' for which no ahead of time (AOT) code was generated.
```

**What could be the reason for this and how can I fix it?**

Comment: Maybe this AOT compilation doesn't support generics at all?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski But I have a lot of other generic types and methods and the rest of the project works just fine ... why exactly should only this one fail? And well I don't really know what the AOT does/means to be honest ^^

Comment: I tried to use above code in UWP project, the visual studio told that we need upgrade current c# 7.0 to 7.1. could you check if `LangVersion` is 7.1?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT yes using `value = default;` instead of `value = default(T);` is a c# 7.1 feature

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I don't know what exactly you are talking about or where I could see that but since it is a 7.1 feature and I don't get compile time errors I would think so yes

Comment: @derHugo what is your unity version?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 `2019.3.3f1`

Comment: @derHugo "TrygetValue" != "TryGetValue"?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 Thank that was just a typo in the question ;) Otherwise it would already be a compile time error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after some further research and tests the conclusion to why this happened is as follows:

Since according method was part of an interface and only either called via interface or via the base class the `Example.TryGetValue` method was never explicitly called via this class.

Since the `Example` class lives in a different Assembly than the interface and Base class the code for `Example.TryGetValue` was somehow stripped of on compile time (since the compiler thinks it is never used anyway) and therefore missing later in the build.

---

I now know the reason and what to have in mind for the future but not yet a real solution except having an explicit implementation and calling that so it is not stripped of...

Comment: Which class is it that implements the interface explicitly? Example or BaseExample or both?

Comment: If `BaseExample` implements the interface then so does `Example` right? ;) It's `BaseExample` in this case

Comment: I was wondering if it changed the way it stripped if you explicitly implemented the interface on Example, instead of just through the inheritance of the Base class.

Answer (score 3):

To work around an AOT issue like this, you can force the compiler to generate the proper code. You can add the following example method in your class:

```
public void UsedOnlyForAOTCodeGeneration() 
{
    // YOUR CODE HERE

    // Include an exception so we can be sure to know if this method is ever called.
    throw new InvalidOperationException(@"This method is used for AOT code generation only. 
    Do not call it at runtime.");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For my specific case (if it helps anyone) I was using

```
WrapperMethod<WeatherFrameInfo[]>();

WrapperMethod<T>() {
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
}
```

Which lead to the error:

```
2022/03/17 14:53:32.888 13468 13524 Error Unity ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to call method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[WeatherFrameInfo, ScriptsAssembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]::.cctor' for which no ahead of time (AOT) code was generated.
2022/03/17 14:53:32.888 13468 13524 Error Unity   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
2022/03/17 14:53:32.888 13468 13524 Error Unity   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.LateBoundReflectionDelegateFactory+<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1[T].<CreateDefaultConstructor>b__1 () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
2022/03/17 14:53:32.888 13468 13524 Error Unity   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract.CreateTemporaryCollection () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
2022/03/17 14:53:32.888 13468 13524 Error Unity   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewList (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract contract, System.Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
2022/03/17 14:53:32.888 13468 13524 Error Unity   at Newtons
```

I theorized that **Newtonsoft** is converting my array input to a `List` at some point so I refactored my code to do that *ahead of time* and violá

```
WrapperMethod<List<WeatherFrameInfo>>();

WrapperMethod<T>() {
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
}
```

Comment: Oh that's a nasty one as well!